# How to submit custom POST form via cURL PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, php-curl

I'm making a theme wordpress use childtheme in localhost. I had a basic form html in `footer.php`:

```
<form method="post">     
    <input name="FNAME" type="text">
    <input name="LNAME" type="text">
    <input name="EMAIL" type="email">
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Now , I want to submit form to an api url via cURL php. I know code to set up cURL like this:

```
$data =  $_POST;

$curl = curl_init();

$options =array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'link_to_url',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I want to when form is submitted , POST data will send via this cURL, But I don't know where I should place this code and how to process it. I think it maybe placed in a function in `function.php` but I don't know how to write it .Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to execute said code within the same file can do something like this:

```
<?php
// any other php code above
if(isset($_POST["infoForm"])) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    $data = array(
        'post_request_name_for_fName' => $_POST["FNAME"],
        'post_request_name_for_lName' => $_POST["FNAME"],
        'post_request_name_for_email' => $_POST["EMAIL"]       
     );

    $options =array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'link_to_url',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
// any other php code below
?>
```

and set the HTML to this:

```
<form method="post">     
    <input name="FNAME" type="text">
    <input name="LNAME" type="text">
    <input name="EMAIL" type="email">
    <button type="submit" name="infoForm">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Now here's the explanation behind it. You set the `name` of your submit button to `infoForm` (or whatever else you want it to be) so the PHP can know which form is posted and when. You then use `if(isset($_POST["infoForm"]))` to check whether the form was posted, and then you execute the lower code to post it.

The `$_POST["FNAME"]` and other variants check the data found in each one of the inputs and sets that to a value of the `$data` array. Then you can change all the values of `post_request_name_for_fName` to whatever the values for your post request need it to be (i.e.; if you're post request needs a 'name' and 'email' parameter, just change the values above as needed).

If you also want to transition to a different page you can make a new file (i.e.; post.php) and add the code in their without the if(isset), and set your html as this:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">     
    <input name="FNAME" type="text">
    <input name="LNAME" type="text">
    <input name="EMAIL" type="email">
    <button type="submit" name="infoForm">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I put excute code in the same file, how can I prevent a browser resubmision form when reload page ?

Comment: On your ``<form>`` tag add the following attribute: ``onSubmit="return false;"``, so the form would look like this ``<form method="post" onSubmit="return false;">``

Comment: `onsubmit="return false"` prevent completely form submit. I mean when I submited form success, and I reload the page, and the page appeared an alert `confirm form resubmission`. So I don't want it appears. How could I do ?